# Teamcity Visual Studio sln Targets not found (projects inside project folder)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, teamcity

Im trying to get my teamcity build up and running for a Visual studio solution with multiple projects.

I have created a build step type: Visual Studio sln with the correct solution path (it runs without a target)

I need to build only for a subset of projects. After reading some articles and other questions i think i need to add something like: ProjectName:Rebuild Or SolutionFolder/ProjectName:Rebuild but whatever i type into the Targets field, it will fail me:(

Hope someone will have the answer to this issue.

[EDIT]
To elaborate on why i need this, my solution looks like this:

Solution:
    Libraries (proj folder)
        - SolutionName.Core        <--- probably need to build this too
        - SolutionName.Data        <--- probably need to build this too
        ...
    SolutionName.Instances (project folder)
        - SolutionName.Default     <--- I only want to build this one.
        - SolutionName.BuildA
        - SolutionName.BuildB      <--- and this one.
        - SolutionName.BuildC
        - SolutionName.BuildD

SO A C AND D will never build (in the foreseeable future this solution will have way more projects, so the build process is growing fast.
[/EDIT]

Comment: What is the error message, what's in the log?

Comment: The error is pretty simple:
Z:\TeamCityData\BuildAgent2\work\dafb8069c5ac3d3c\XXXSolution.sln.metaproj error MSB4057: The target ""XXXProject" does not exist in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to configure what to build directly in the solution. Then in TeamCity use `Target=Rebuild` and `ConfigurationName=Release`.

Right click in the Solution Explorer on the solution and select "Configuration Manager". Change the "Active solution configuration" to "Release". Then uncheck build on selected projects.

[image]

Comment: Hi David, Thank you this works fine. Still got an error but i think its related to not having build the whole solution.

ASPNETCOMPILER error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'SolutionName.Default' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format